# How to get some space below my last list item alone- android

Tags: android, listview

I have a list whose height is set to "fill parent". everything works fine but my last item in list touches the bottom of my screen. how can i get some space below my last list item.

Comment: I think this is the best and simple answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21842756/2318558

Answer (score 3):

You can add an empty view as footer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)

AFAIK there's no way to do that only with XML, you can declare the footer in XML and inflate, or create programmatically

Here is a 3-liner to add a spacer programmatically:

```
View listFooter = new View(this);
listFooter.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 70)));
listView.addFooterView(listFooter);
```

Comment: there is a way to do it using XML since API Level 14. Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

uhmm.. seeing that you don't want padding, print a blank line (or transparent text) on a textview located after your listview. Or print a "extra" item on your listview.

Comment: The only valid answer here is the "extra item". The other suggestion has the same effect as margin, and that's also unwanted.

Comment: You should consider voting positive.

Comment: Maybe I should consider voting negative, because the answer contains incorrect suggestions, and the "valid" one is still not good.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [Space widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

can simply set the margin in the list ............

if need only bottom margin then use : android:layout_marginBottom=

Comment: Thats a good idea but that doesn't meet my requirement exactly. If i set margin, that makes a boundary for the entire listView, not for the last item alone. I just need space below last element alone. In precise, just like a divider after the last item also.

Comment: can you attach the screenshot of screen ... to better understand BG and border requirmant?

Comment: this is how my list looks now.   https://picasaweb.google.com/117966123187082962855/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCMSsrefhwrOrugE#5747473585944696626   following link shows how do i want my list to be   https://picasaweb.google.com/117966123187082962855/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCMSsrefhwrOrugE#5747473572341255618

Comment: then what's wrong with margin if here it looks you can set actvity bg color  (root view bg color) and list bg color same ? more over padding can also work fine for you.......

Comment: I dont want to set margin or padding because I want my list to be stretched upto the bottom margin of the parent view. For good user experience only, i want to make a divider after last element also.

Comment: margin can also do same for you but for now you can use padding as simple option...