# How can I add blank space to the end of a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-listview, padding

I have a number of elements in a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) that scroll off the screen.

I would like there to be blank space at the end of the View. That is, the user should be able to scroll past the last element such that the last element is in the middle of the viewport.

I could use an [OverScroller](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/OverScroller.html), but I think that would only enable the View to have a bouncy effect like one often sees on the iPhone.

Is there something I might have overlooked?

The scrolled-to-the-botton screen should look something like this:
[image: Android mockup where there are a number of labels the last of which is near the middle of the screen]

Comment: anything I can think of would be a hack since listview doesn't work that way... but you could adjust the height of the last view in the list in getView if position == count - 1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Inflate any layout of your choice (this could be an XML of and ImageView with no drawable and with set height and width of your choice)
2. Measure the screen height and create new LayoutParams and set the height of it to 1/2 of the screen height
3. Set the new layout params on your inflated view
4. Use the ListView's [`addFooterView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) method to add that view to the bottom of your list (there is also an `addHeaderView()`)

Code to measure screen height

```
 WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
 Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
 int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

Code to set half screen height:

```
 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistviewfooter, container, false);
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = layout.getLayoutParams();
 lp.height = screenHeight/2;
 layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
 myListView.addFooterView(layout);
```

An Aside:
When you add a footer or header view to any listview, it has to be done before adding the adapter.  Also, if you need to get your adapter class after doing this you will need to know calling the listview's adapter by `getAdapter()` will return an instance of [HeaderViewListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html) in which you will need to call its [getWrappedAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html#getWrappedAdapter%28%29) method
Something like this :

```
 MyAdapterClassInstance myAdapter = (MyAdapterClassInstance) ((HeaderViewListAdapter) myListView.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter();
```

Comment: make footer view half of screen.

Comment: from API 13 Display.getHeight() was depracated [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getHeight())

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for being mostly right. I changed the method to `addFooterView()`. :)

Comment: Wow. So simple yet I never tought about that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 46):

The accepted answer is too complicated, and addFooterView is not for this kind of thing. The proper and simpler way is to set the paddingTop and paddingBottom, and you need to set clipToPadding to "false". In your list view or grid view, add the following:

```
    android:paddingTop="100dp"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
```

You'll get blank space at the top and the bottom that moves with your finger scroll.

Comment: Anybody noticed that the ListView doesn't scroll if you touch the padding? In my case the padding could be as much as 2/3 of the screen height so this won't work for me. Unless anybody knows how to make it scrollable?

Comment: This is the simpliest answer.. We can combine this one with @petey's to set the bottom blank space to 1/2 of screen height. Just add this code `yourListView.setPadding(0,0,0,height/2)`

Comment: @darnmason you are right only for bottom padding, header padding is responsive to touch, and your comment worth up voting :)

Answer (score 0):

this 100% works.
in adapter set your code like this

```
   //in getCount
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
   return ArrayList.size()+1;
      }
    //in getview make your code like this
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);

    if(i<getCount()-1) {
     //your code
    }
    else{
    ViewGroup itemContainer =(ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.container);
                itemContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    Return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple listviews in your app, create an xml of a footer, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="200dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"></LinearLayout>
```

and then in the code, use this:

```
listView.addFooterView(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.empty200, null));
```

Comment: make sure you use minHeight in the empty footer view, or something else that guarantees that your view will have a height (listview sometimes adjusts heights of things)

Answer (score 0):

This do the job in a simple way

```
android:paddingBottom="100dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Answer (score -3):

Try the followings:

```
View footer = new View(getActivity());
footer.setLayoutParams( new AbsListView.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 100 )); 
// 100 is the height, you can change it.
mListView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);
```